# type parameter t has incompatible upper bounds view and webview

Tags: java, android

```
type parameter t has incompatible upper bounds view and webview
```

this error comes when I'm trying to setup a simple web view. I've tried most solutions from stackoverflow with no luck.

I'm new to Android Development.

Tried,
1. Adding this to gradle

`dataBinding enabled = true`

2. Clear, Rebuild, Invalidate Cache and Restart

Here is the code,

```
public class WebView extends AppCompatActivity {

String url = "";
WebView mWebView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //Error comes here redline below findViewById

    }
}
```

Comment: i think you will have to change the class name, you are using system class WebView and your own class WebView, so you might have mixed those up. if not, post your layout... check your imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is named WebView which is also the name of the android system class WebView.

Then you are declaring mWebView as a WebView. Here you did not explicitly tell the compiler to use WebView the android system class. compiler thinks it is a class object of the class you made. to avoid this you need to explicitly give the full path of the android system Webview there.

Since your class does not extend View and the compiler thinks mWebView is of your class type, ofcourse it can't cast an actual web view ( the android system one ) to your variable.

In short, please rename your class to something else for your own sake.

Answer (score 0):

just change the name of your class to another name like MyWebView and dont use Java keywords as your class name

Answer (score 0):

change  name your class to anything except WebView